Inter-Rater Reliability calculation for multi-attribute annotation by multiple raters
I want to calculate IRR for my annotation project. IRR metrics can be Krippendorff-alpha , GWET-AC1/AC2 or others.
Here is my project annotation description,
Number of raters = 3
Number of attributes =5
Number of row samples = Between 100 and 1000

Here attributes basically means number of factors on which a final decision has to be made.
For example, Suppose there is a a full human body health checkup data, where attributes are sugar-level, colestrol-level, Vitamin, Thyroid, Liver Functioning Test. Finally there is completely-fit/partially-fit/not-fit label is there that has to decided based on the above attributes.

How should I formulate it for calculating Krippendorff-alpha like metrics to find the raters reliability?
I'm bit new to this domain. I just went through some blogs and resources available, but they are not including multiple attributes, Just different raters are annotating a single attribute.
